# For how long does the Earth 'stand still' in the original "The Day The Earth Stood Still"?

Tags: movie, the-day-the-earth-stood-still

In *The Day The Earth Stood Still* (the 1951 movie), how long does Klaatu set up the 'stood still' part to last? Was it an hour?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Day_the_Earth_Stood_Still) and [AMC TV's quiz](http://www.amctv.com/games/movie-challenge/1969), 30 minutes.

[image: Screencap of AMC quiz]